# rpm spec: is possible to automatize the creation of tar.gz archive before prep?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I want to build a rpm from git project.
In this case the command

```
git archive
```

Cannot work and so I use the old method

```
git clone repo
tar -cvf file.tar.gz repo
```

If I try to build the rpm without tar.gz cannot start.
So I have "split" the process in two parts
One is the shell script.sh which create the archive

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT=https://gitproject..
NAME=gitproject
VERSION=$(date +%mY)

git clone $GIT $NAME-$VERSION
tar -cvf $NAME-$VERSION.tar.gz $NAME-$VERSION
```

The second is the spec

My question is..is possible to put the shell script commands in the spec(maybe I will change the syntax of variables) to obtain a total automatic .spec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several projects which are doing this. Choose yourself:

1. [Tito](https://github.com/dgoodwin/tito) ([blog post](http://miroslav.suchy.cz/blog/archives/2013/12/29/how_to_build_in_copr/index.html)) - I prefer this one.
2. [dgroc](https://github.com/pypingou/dgroc) ([blog post](http://blog.pingoured.fr/index.php?post/2014/03/20/Introducing-dgroc))
3. [mock-scm](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/mock/wiki/Plugin-Scm)
4. [rpkg-util](https://pagure.io/rpkg-util)